# What is the temperature of the clear day sky from the surface of Earth?

Tags: temperature, radiation, atmospheric-science, geophysics

I read this thread: [What is the temperature of the clear night sky from the surface of Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153839/what-is-the-temperature-of-the-clear-night-sky-from-the-surface-of-earth)

I don't know if this equation is also valid for day time. I don't think it is. I suppose the temperature must be higher at day time.

Comment: The clear sky doesn't absorb solar radiation (fortunately).  It only scatters a little (Rayligh scattering).  In first approximation the answer will be the same.  The formula in the linked question is slightly more than a first approximation, though, so it may not be identical.